# xcopy works, but doesn't

Tags: windows, batch, xcopy

Really odd behavoir on xcopy.  I have a batch file as follows

"<=create a backup of a service - works fine, backup files created correctly=>"

```
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
cd C:\BakTemp
ren "BAKup.sql" "BAKup(%mydate%_%mytime%).sql"
xcopy /M /Y /S "C:\BakTemp" "R:\ConFigBAKups\Backups_for_%mydate%_%mytime%\"
```

the xcopy command fails with an Invalid drive specification msg, but works fine up to then.

If I then cut and paste the above file and remove the section which creates the files at the start into a new batchfile - it copies the files created by the failed previous batchfile perfectly.

ie ... this works

```
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
cd C:\BakTemp
xcopy /M /Y /S "C:\BakTemp" "R:\ConFigBAKups\Backups_for_%mydate%_%mytime%\"
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing on the rename command itself?

Comment: 100 per cent cerain.  I have watched the files being created and then renamed.  I have also set the echo on and watched the error msg report Invalid drive specification.  bat being run in elevated mode or manually run as administrator makes no difference in either case.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone looking at thios in the future, I got this to work by using the "\Server\path" form and removing the switches.  I have no idea why.